# redbeanphp - How to display the id of a foreign key as text

Tags: php

I have a problem in the implementation. 
I wanted to display all entries of the foreign key in the drop-down list, but it displays only the id. I'm using redbeanphp. Maybe someone knows how to implement it here?

```
$shared = R::findAll( 'template_workers');

echo ('<table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-inverse">
                    <tr> 
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>phrase</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead> 
                <tbody>');
      foreach($shared as $row){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th class="col col-lg-2">'.$row['id'].'</th>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['template_id'].'</td>'; 
        echo '<td>'.$row['workers_id'].'</td>'; 
    }
    echo ('</tbody></table>');
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: because you are `echo` ing `id` only so it will dispaly id.

Comment: Thank you! It work))
I apologize for my stupidity